# AWS Glue: Primary Key comes Null

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I'm setting up a new job in AWS Glue, It takes a MySQL (AWS RDS) table and copy the data to Postgresql (AWS RDS), but the job execution fails because the primary key always comes as a null value. I did a test deleting the primary key constraint, and the job works!.

Connections:
I have two JDBC connections, Mysql and Postgresql.

Crawler
Just one crawler to identify my table schema

Mysql table:
I have a "MyGuests" table following schema:
- person_id (primary key)
- firstname
- Lastname
- reg_date
- email

And the Postgresql replica looks the same.

I'd like to know why it happens? Or What am I missing?